# Can't use heart_rate sensor in android studio

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have a problem getting data from my heart_rate_sensor. If I use a light sensor, it works perfectly but when it comes to the other sensor it doesn´t.
Here`s my activity.java file:

```
package com.example.smartwatchprueba2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.smartwatchprueba2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView,mTextView1;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());


        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(this.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        Sensor sensorLuz = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
        Sensor sensorRitmoCardiaco = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);

        sensorManager.registerListener(listener, sensorLuz, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(listener1, sensorRitmoCardiaco, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);



        mTextView = binding.textView;
        mTextView1=binding.textView1;



    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (sensorManager != null) {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener);
           sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener1);
        }
    }

    SensorEventListener listener=new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float value = sensorEvent.values[0];
            mTextView.setText("Current light level is " + value + " lx");

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };

    SensorEventListener listener1=new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            float value1 = sensorEvent.values[0];
            mTextView.setText("Current heart rate is: " + value1);

        }


        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };
}
```

I thought it could be something with the permission, but I have included Body_sensors permission and it doesn`t work. Here`s my manifest file so you can see all the permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.smartwatchprueba2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You have declared in your manifest that your app uses the `BODY_SENSORS` permission. But where in your code do you actually request the user to grant your app that permission?

Comment: I see what you mean @Michael. First of all, thank you for your response. I’m new in android and there are a lot of things I don’t know. How do I ask the user to grant the permission? Because I thought that declaring the permission in the mannifest file was enough

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/permissions

Comment: @Michael I’ve read the link you’ve sent, and I see what I have to do but it doesn’t explain how to do it